# Serving Temporary Pages with NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'd like to start by letting everyone know that I am new to coding in node. With that out of the way let me explain what I am trying to build, I'm trying to build a site where a user can use a button on the main page to visit a page that has a randomized route, but only once. So once you have visited that route, you need to click on the link again to see the same contents but on a different route. That will ensure users have to click on the button and can't just cheat the system by entering the same link over and over. So in basic terms I need the app to:

-Temporarily serve a HTML form (to get information) on a randomized route/link (could be for a single request or for some time, say 10 minutes)

-Delete that route/link

-Start over

Here is the code I have so far:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = new express();
const fs = require('fs');
var link = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 0) + 0)
var changingroute = function (req, res, next) {
    app.get('/' + link, function(req, res){
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/download.html');
    });
    setTimeout(endroute, 1000)
        function endroute() {
            app.delete('/' + link)
            console.log('Route Closed: LocalHost:8080/', link);
        }
    link = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 0) + 0)
    console.log('Route Opened: localhost:8080/',link);
    next()
}

//app.use(changingroute);
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.renderFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.get('/' + link, function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/download.html', '/public/download.html', function(err, res) {
        if (!err) {
            res.setHeader('Location', pathname + '/');
        }
    });
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('app running');
    console.log(`Route Opened: http://localhost:8080/${link}`);
});
```

Explanation:
The current code doesn't do what I would like it to. As you can probably tell changingroute isn't used, the app.use is commented. What it did do was create new routes every time a request was made but it wouldn't close the route afterwards. Where I was last with this code was testing out something someone else did on SO but it kind of differed from what I am trying to do : [Serving Temporary Files with NodeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484350/serving-temporary-files-with-nodejs). With their code you can put up files to download but only once but that doesn't really translate to routes and pages as I understand. I get errors like "cannot replace header" if I try and change the page it displays, or if I try and close the route. I haven't seen any tutorials online that show how to make temporary routes, or maybe I haven't used the right keywords. If you have any advice on where I should look or what I should try please let me know. I would really appreciate it!