# I want to start a simple http web server but this isn't working

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log("User request received");
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "Text/plain"});
    fs.createReadStream(process.argv[3]).pipe(response);
    response.end();
}).listen(process.argv[2]);

console.log("Server is running...");
```

This program takes the port number and the file path as command line parameters.
When I run it in node, even though I pass the correct command line arguments, the file is not served when accessed from the browser

I don't know where the error is occurring

Comment: Please post the error you are getting

Comment: is the process variable defined?

Comment: process is a global variable in node@Grüse

Comment: I figured the error and rectified it but the file is not being displayed once I access from browser @Lofus

Comment: Is the file being displayed in the browser once requested? @Sweet_Pete

Comment: Nope, that's why I removed my previous comment :|

Comment: So what could be a solution to this? really confused @Sweet_Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the best answer but it looks like the call to response.end() is closing the stream before the file is served.  Following the logic on this answer:

[createReadStream().pipe() Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962085/createreadstream-pipe-callback)

You need a callback on when the stream closes, so I found this works but again, I don't know if this is the most elegant solution:

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
console.log("User request received");
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "Text/plain"});
var t = fs.createReadStream(process.argv[3]).pipe(response);

t.on('close', function(){
    response.end();
});

}).listen(process.argv[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Sweet_Pete