# How to find that upload is completed - Node Express

Tags: node.js, express

In Node Express, I am reading a locally saved zip file and sending it to a Java servlet using request module.

```
var req = require('request');
//Define a read stream from our source zip file
 var source = fs.createReadStream('abc.zip');
//Send our data via POST request
source.pipe(req.post('http://myhost:8080/myservlets/uploadzip')); 
//Can I cleanup abc.zip here?
```

After the zip is uploaded, I need to clean up the zip from the node server. The challenge that I am facing is that how to find that zip upload has completed? Is there a way to get a promise when upload completes or define a callback, so that I can put the zip cleanup code only after upload completes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [createReadStream().pipe() Callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962085/createreadstream-pipe-callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the same as asked here: [createReadStream().pipe() Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962085/createreadstream-pipe-callback)
For your case it should work like:

```
source.on('close', function(){
  fs.unlink('abc.zip');
});
```

Meaning you just have to overwrite the callback included in `fs`. In *loganfsmyth*'s answer you can find a way to extend this for keeping files, which had errors on submitting by overwriting the `error` callback.