# NodeJS Express Dynamic File Download

Tags: node.js, express

I want the user to be able to query the database and download a nicely formatted txt file with their results. What is the best way of doing this? Right now I write to a temp file, let the user download it, and then delete the accumulated files once a week. Is there a NodeJS way of doing this?

Comment: how do you read your data? from what database or file?

Comment: Set the correct http headers and just send the result from the database? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server

Comment: And how do you format the file, with node or something else?

Comment: Database is elasticsearch. I write the results to a text file using NodeJS and send that text file.