# How to make browser download json returned from rest service

Tags: json, rest, angularjs, download, sitebricks

The frameworks i'm using are AngularJS(client-side) and Sitebricks(server-side).
I want to return a list of objects into json and make the client download that json by prompting the user where he wants to save the file.

I accept all kind of propositions.
Cheers in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server

Comment: well , what bothers me is that there is an actual file on the server. I cannot create any files on the server so i cannot send files. I guess i can just create a stream and send the string data from the server and on the client to read the stream. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create the file in the browser, and save it to the user's local machine.  One method is presented here, but it doesn't work in IE [Javascript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vUdyD/

```
$(function() {
  function exportToCsv() {
        var myCsv = "Col1,Col2,Col3\nval1,val2,val3";

        window.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(myCsv));
    }

    var button = document.getElementById('b');
    button.addEventListener('click', exportToCsv);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the HTML5 `download` attribute. It is not perfect and browser support

```
<!-- will download as "expenses.pdf" -->
<a href="/files/adlafjlxjewfasd89asd8f.pdf" download="expenses.pdf">Download Your Expense    Report</a>
```

Demo: http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute

Support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: Well here again is the situation with having a file on the server. but i can't create any files on the server.. so i can't pass file to the client.