# res.download() not working in my case

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using nodejs and expressjs framework to download a file 'jsonFile.json' from server.

i am using the following code

```
res.get('/download', function(req, res) {
         res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=jsonFile.json');
          res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/json');
          res.download(__dirname + 'jsonFile.json');
        }
      });
```

But this results into a response with whole content of file.

i was expecting browser to ask me to save the file in local disk.

How do i save the file in local disk.???

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Let Express set the correct headers and just do this:

```
res.get('/download', function(req, res) {
  res.download(__dirname + 'jsonFile.json', 'jsonFile.json');
});
```

([doc](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.download))

**EDIT:** since you're requesting `/download` through an AJAX call, you have to change your setup because most (all?) browsers will not show a download dialog in that case.

Instead, you can create a new window from your front end code to trigger the dialog:

```
window.open('/download?foo=bar&xxx=yyy');
```

Comment: also if i remove the '/' in the path name.. i get 404

Comment: yes i have removed the headers and result is same and still i am not getting the expected result. browser should ask to save file on disk,

Comment: @Koka which browser? It works fine in Chrome, FF and Safari for me. Also, are you opening `/download` directly, or through something like AJAX?

Comment: i means with the same.. i have added he res.get('/download' ... line but result is same.. getting the response filled with file content.

Comment: i am using firefox on ubuntu 12,04

Comment: demo from http://runnable.com/UpIbxCTySek9AAA2/output gives me exact result.. but not from the code on my local machine

Comment: @Koka I don't think AJAX calls trigger a download action in any browser, so that's not going to work. If you want to present the user with a download dialog, you should probably use `window.open()`.

Comment: can i send some query parameters (an array of values) dynamically with the window.open()..??

Comment: thanks for your answer.. but how do i send a parameter of array of values,.. not just two static parameters

Comment: @robertklep thanks window.open worked for me. But i am facing a new issue. My service sends a zip file as response. But in my case only an empty zip file is downloaded

Comment: @Apoorvasahay if you create a new question (including the code you're using to create and send back the ZIP file), I'll have a look if you want.

Comment: @robertklep here is the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733278/why-res-download-is-downloading-an-empty-zip-file

Answer (score 10):

Just to confirm what @robert said,

because this thing turned my head for two days,
instead of using an ajax call, open a new window with your ajax request location, for example:

```
window.open("http://yourserver.com/api/link?a=3&b=4")
```

hope this helps someone.

Comment: 2022 Update: Still works great. Wow, thank you so much, I have been trying to figure this out for days.

Comment: So simple, yet makes so much sense.