# why res.download is downloading an empty zip file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, download

I am using expressjs to develop my app. I have written a service which downloads the file at client using `res.download(filepath, filename)`. Following is my service.

```
router.route('/downloadFile').get(function(req,res){
    var filter = url.parse(req.url, true).query.filter;

    Model.find({label:filter}).exec()
    .catch(function(err){
        console.error(err);
    })
    .then(function(data){
        var fileTobeDownloadedPath = foo(); //returns a zip file path which belongs to a location in my temp folder in project

        res.download(fileTobeDownloadedPath, path.parse(fileTobeDownloadedPath).base);
    });
});
```

Here is my frontend javascript code

```
$(document).on('click','#btnDownload', function(event) {
  // I am populating the values of the array using some javascript query
  window.open('/downloadFile?filter=' + angular.element('[ng-controller=mainCtrl]').scope().mainCtrlObj.modalContent.label +
              '&tags=' + angular.element('[ng-controller=mainCtrl]').scope().mainCtrlObj.modalContent.tags.toString() +
              '&sizes=' + sizes.toString() + '&formats=' + formats.toString());
});
```

Depending upon the checkbox selected by the user on the frontend, service will either call res.download with zip file path as the argument or single file path. But when I select multiple options and click download I should have a zip file downloaded.

File is currently getting downloaded but the zip file size is 0 byte and there is no file in the zip file.

Please let me know what has gone wrong. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried to download the file directly (by opening `/downloadFile` in your browser, and also without the database interaction)?

Comment: @robertklep I tried calling the service in my browser as well. The zip file is getting downloaded but it does not contain anything

Comment: And you're sure that the file on the server is correct? Do you have any other Express middleware that may be causing the issue? What does your browser's dev tools say about the file request (like the `Content-Length` header from the response)?

Comment: @robertklep yes, I am actually using the node archiver to create a zip file which is sitting in my project directory and it contains files.

Comment: In that case, I have no idea why it's not working properly. Again, I would suggest that you take a look at the response headers/data in your browser to see if something is off there.

Comment: I am having the same issue... Files on server look perfect, file served to client is 0-bytes...

Anyone ever get this figured out?

Answer (score -1):

Might be too late but this won't work as the function is not defined as async, make it async basically you have started converting the file to zip and the response is send before even finishing the zip file.

so,

```
router.route('/downloadFile').get(function(req,res){
var filter = await url.parse(req.url, true).query.filter;

Model.find({label:filter}).exec()
.catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
})
.then(async function(data){
 var fileTobeDownloadedPath = await foo(); //returns a zip file path 
which belongs to a location in my temp folder in project

res.download(fileTobeDownloadedPath,  
path.parse(fileTobeDownloadedPath).base);
});
});
```

This should work, if this doesn't work you have to try another ways to make it synchronous.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).