# How to send file in a request and download the file within the response without redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I an trying to create a service which takes a `xlsx` template file and response a populated `xlsx` file with some values. What I have done so far is,

index.html

```
<input name="file" type="file" onchange="callthis()"/>
```

script.js

```
// callthis sends the file from client to server
function callthis() {
var formData = new FormData($(this).files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/uploadTemplate',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
}
```

serverRouter.js

```
router.post('/uploadTemplate', function(req, res, next){
    let uploadedFilePath = null;

    // I'm using multer for handling formdata in the server
    var upload = multer({ dest: Locator.temp.temp });

    //configure the multer
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, callback) {
            callback(null, Locator.temp.temp);
        },
        filename: function (req, file, callback) {
            uploadedFilePath = file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.xlsx';
            callback(null, uploadedFilePath);
        }
    });

    var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('file');

    //in here i am uploading the file.

    //and reading the file ugin XLSX modules.

    //doing some changes to xlsx json object

    //and write the data to a file in a temp folder

    //i'm using res.download method to send downloadable file back to client 
     res.download(Path.join(Locator.temp.temp, uploadedFilePath));
    });
})
```

Using above codes, i could upload the file and get response. success method prints out details i added with some unreadable characters. But i could not download the file.

How can i download the file. Are there any different and better approach for this situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [res.download() not working in my case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176982/res-download-not-working-in-my-case)

Comment: nope. it's working when we navigate to url. but in this case i dont want to navigate to the url

Answer (score 0):

You can't attach a download to an AJAX request.  You will have to send the download URL in the AJAX response and then have your client side script open the URL

In the server:

```
let response = {downloadUrl: Path.join(Locator.temp.temp, uploadedFilePath)}
res.json(response)
```

In the client:

```
window.open(ajaxResponse.downloadUrl);
```