# res.download() not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

My aim is to download files on browser window with res.download() and I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176982/res-download-not-working-in-my-case) post.But file is not getting downloaded in the browser.In my console(grunt) it returns 200 response but noting happens on the front end.
Controller:

```
$http.get('/api/knowledges/file_download/?filepath='+fileDownload.file_details.path).success(function(data){
            console.log("and the api returned success")
        });
```

Api:

```
res.download(req.query.filepath, 'my.pdf');
```

And this is the JSON which I am giving to the server:

```
fileDownload=  {
    destination:"server/uploads/docs"
    encoding:"7bit"
    fieldname:"file"
    filename:"9b129f186ca7c534dbfb90e6c2762226"
    mimetype:"application/pdf"
    originalname:"Dress Code.pdf"
    path:"server\uploads\docs\9b129f186ca7c534dbfb90e6c2762226"
    size:397860}
```

Comment: You can't trigger downloads from XHR requests, here's a decent solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43523297

Comment: Nah,I am using node and angular to accomplish the task.Javascript will not be handy enough to solve it.

Comment: @robertklep how is the question the EXACT duplicate of mine?

Comment: I cant see any api code in that question.My query is why my res.download() ain't workin

Comment: Your issue isn't `res.download()` not working (because it's working just fine; like you wrote yourself, _"it returns a 200 response"_), the issue is that you can't trigger a browser download from an XHR response. The question I linked to provides a solution for that. The other link I provided, in my comment, also provides a solution.

Comment: @robertklep it is giving a 200 response online when I am downloading the file for the very first time.And it is throwing an error after that which is:

Comment: server\uploads\docs\50dbe0e232e190fd377439293a0dc36b
GET /api/knowledges/file_download/?filepath=server\uploads\docs\50dbe0e232e190fd
377439293a0dc36b 304 422ms
error thrown
{ Error: Request aborted
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (C:\project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:
941:17)
    at runCallback (timers.js:637:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:610:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:582:5) code: 'ECONNAB
ORT' }

Comment: Are you passing a callback function to `res.download()`? And which version of Express are you using?

Comment: @robertklep yes I am using callback to console log the error and my express details are {"express": "~4.9.0",
    "express-jwt": "^3.0.0",
    "express-session": "~1.0.2"}

Comment: Did you implement the answer in the linked question to see if that fixes the download?

Comment: yes.It dint help

Comment: If you add the specific issues that you are seeing to your question, I'll vote to reopen it (although I think that the `ECONNABORT` is a red herring, and that there's nothing wrong with `res.download()`).

Comment: I have tried using file stream and below is the code...Now I am getting 200 response for each and every click but still not getting any download in the browser :

Comment: var file=req.query.filepath;
  var filename = path.basename(file);
  var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
  res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);
  var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  filestream.pipe(res);

Comment: As long as you keep requesting the URL using XHR (with `$http.get()`), you will never get a download dialog. The link in my very first comment (http://stackoverflow.com/a/43523297/893780) provides a solution, and a similar solution is also provided for the duplicate question (but read that question and its answer _carefully_; it will use `$http.get()` but only to retrieve the URL to download; you already have that URL, so the only thing you have to implement is the part after _"//=== add <a> tag and trigger click ==="_)

Comment: Nah man.My file is on server...I cant access that just by giving the route.Please understand the question before marking it as a duplicate.

Comment: You know the URL of the file on the client, don't you? `/api/knowledges/file_download/?filepath='+fileDownload.file_details.path`. There's nothing stopping you from plugging that URL into the code that's being shown.

Comment: You mean something like this?

Comment: $scope.download=function(fileDownload){

     
  function downloadFile(filePath){
    console.log("download funcion invoked");
    console.log(filePath);
    var link=document.createElement('a');
    link.href = filePath;
    link.download = filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    link.click();
}
downloadFile('/api/knowledges/file_download/?filepath='+fileDownload.file_‌​details.path);
    }

Comment: Use `link.download = "my.pdf"` instead of `filePath.substr(...)`.

Comment: I got this error:Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task
    Warning: Running "babel:server" (babel) task
Warning: client/app/getNotes/getNotes.controller.js: Unexpected character '?' (2
1:75) Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Comment: The code you pasted contains unprintable characters, so you need to clean it up first.

Comment: Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task
Warning: Running "babel:server" (babel) task
Warning: client/app/getNotes/getNotes.controller.js: Unexpected character '?' (21:75) Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Comment: Hello,Now file is getting downloaded in my browser but the content is not being loaded.Its like its a blank pdf.