# Downloading file via REST API web method

Tags: node.js

I have a REST API developed in node js. One of my routes downloads a file and i am able to download the file too. But i am also trying to retain the actual file name when sending across. I have set the appropriate headers too.

My route is

```
http://localhost/v1/tests/myfile
```

And I have set the following headers,

```
{ 

 'Content-Type': 'application/text', 

 'Content-Length': stat.size, 

 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment',

 'filename': 'sample.txt'

}
```

When I access the route in Chrome or Firefox, the file is downloading as **myfile**. Why is this happening and how do i retain my file name?

Comment: Check this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server

Comment: thanks Roman, that worked. i misunderstood the value of Content-Disposition. My bad!!!