# Express js: How to download a file using POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I use GET, everything works fine. However, I struggle to use POST to achieve the same effect. Here are the code I have tried:

1.

```
app.post("/download", function (req, res) {
    res.download("./path");
});
```

2.

```
app.post("/download", function (req, res) {
    res.attachment("./path");
    res.send("ok");
});
```

3.

```
app.post("/download", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile("./path");
});
```

None of them work. What is the correct way to do this?

EDIT:
I submit a POST request through a HTML form to `/download`. `./path` is a static file. When I use code in method 1, I can see the correct response header and response body in the developer tool. But the browser does not prompt a download.

Comment: which version of express js. are you using. `res.download()` uses res.sendFile() to transfer files. Also res.sendFile() is supported from Express v4.8.0 onwards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download a file from NodeJS Server using Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express)

Comment: @Pinal That question seems not about POST method as I mentioned.

Comment: @hitman4890 I am using node v0.10.32 and express v4.12.3

Comment: can you show the calling method or where the request to download is generated code? Also is `path` is correct?

Comment: @hitman4890 I updated my question, hope it will be clearer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you want, but I have been having the same trouble.
This is what I did in the end:

- *Client* - *See EDIT below* for updated client code

```js
$http.post('/download', /**your data**/ ).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $window.open('/download'); //does the download
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('ERROR: could not download file');
  });
```

- *Server*

```js
// Receive data from the client to write to a file
app.post("/download", function (req, res) {
    // Do whatever with the data
    // Write it to a file etc...
});

// Return the generated file for download
app.get("/download", function (req, res) {
    // Resolve the file path etc... 
    res.download("./path");
});
```

Alternatively, have you just tried calling `$window.open(/download);` from the HTML? This was the main reason why my download did not start. It returned in the XHR and I could see the data, but also did not prompt a download.

***EDIT:**
The client code was not accurate, after some more testing it turned out that I  only needed to do the following on the client:

```js
// NOTE: Ensure that the data to be downloaded has 
// already been packaged/created and is available
$window.open('/download'); //does the download
```