# Download generated PDF using node-html-pdf module

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm using [node-html-pdf](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf) module to generating a PDF file from an `ejs` template I've created, which after it is generated, it gets saved on my server.

Now this works perfectly, but what I really need is when I click a button, it generates the PDF and downloads the file, instead of saving it.

Below you can see the code I have to generate and save the file:

```
var html = null;

ejs.renderFile('./templates/participants.ejs', {users: req.body.users, course: req.body.course, organization: req.body.organization}, function (err, result) {
    if (result) {
        html = result;
    }
    else {
        res.end('An error occurred');
        console.log(err);
    }
});

pdf.create(html).toStream(function(err, stream){
    var file = 'c:' + stream.path; 
    // var file = full path to tmp file (added 'c:' because I'm testing locally right now)
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + file);
    res.download(file, req.body.course.name + '.pdf', function(err){
        if (err) {
           // Handle error, but keep in mind the response may be partially-sent
           // so check res.headersSent
        } else {
           // decrement a download credit, etc.
        }
    });
});
```

I thought that maybe I could you `.toStream` or `.toBuffer` instead of `.toFile`, but I'm quit new at this and in the documentation it doesn't really explain how `.toStream` and `.toBuffer` works (or does). I hope maybe somebody could point me in the right direction? Or at least tell if this is totally wrong and I should look at another solution.

**Update**

I have now tried to checked out @Remy's links but without luck (nothing happens, not even an error, when i run the code), so I have updated my post with my new code (above).

I have also tried @itaylorweb answer, but with same result, nothing happens.

Answer (score 8):

I've just developed a feature using `html-pdf` module.

Below is my code sample:

```
pdf.create(html).toBuffer(function (err, buffer) {
    if (err) return res.send(err);
    res.type('pdf');
    res.end(buffer, 'binary');
});
```

Or you could use Stream like this:

```
pdf.create(html).toStream(function (err, stream) {
    if (err) return res.send(err);
    res.type('pdf');
    stream.pipe(res);
});
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the node-html-pdf docs you would most likely what to utilise below:
You could also set your response header:

```
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');

pdf.create(html).toStream(function(err, stream){
    stream.pipe(res);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7288883/2045854 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/11944984/2045854

Step 1: read your PDF as a stream

Step 2: pipe it to a response

Regards

Remy