# Download csv file node.js

Tags: node.js, csv, download

I am building an app using node.js and trying to download data as a csv file. I am using json2csv (https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv) for this purpose. However, the way I have it configured, the .csv file gets stored in my app's root directory. I want the file to be sent to the user as a download - for example, the file should appear in the user's `/downloads` folder. Here is my current code:

```
var fields = ['car', 'price', 'color'];
var myCars = [
  {
    "car": "Audi",
    "price": 1,
    "color": "blue"
  }, {
    "car": "BMW",
    "price": 1,
    "color": "black"
  }, {
    "car": "Porsche",
    "price": 1,
    "color": "green"
  }
];

json2csv({ data: myCars, fields: fields }, function(err, csv) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  fs.writeFile('file.csv', csv, function(err) { //currently saves file to app's root directory
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('file saved');
  });

});

var file = '../software-project-metric-dashboard/file.csv';
res.download(file, 'testfile.csv');
```

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you or do you plan to use a framework like express or do you just want to have a server for this use only?

Comment: I am using the express framework @cviejo

Comment: Try following this, get back if you encounter any issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express

Comment: don't use fs.writeFile, instead just send the content with the proper content type, the same way you'd send html content to the client.

Answer (score 34):

Use res.send if you use [express](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send).

You have to define a HTTP GET route which looks something like that:

```
app.get("/pathToYourDownload", function (req, res) {
  json2csv({ data: myCars, fields: fields }, function(err, csv) {
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=data.csv');
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    res.status(200).send(csv);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi - I tried this - it doesn't send any error but it doesn't show up in my downloads folder..

Comment: But it does show up in my console network tab as a 304

Comment: hm strange, what if u try to send just some string and not the json.csv, just for testing?

Comment: @Kiechlus's response is correct, but it uses an outdated version of json2csv. When adopting take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv#migrating-from-3x-to-4x

Answer (score 18):

On [express](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express) server:

```
const json2csv = require('json2csv').parse;

const csvString = json2csv(yourDataAsArrayOfObjects);
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=shifts-report.csv');
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
res.status(200).send(csvString);
```

On client (otherwise most of the browsers will not download the file, even you will see the proper response in the network panel):

```
window.open(downloadUrl);
```

Comment: Upvoted this answer because even though I had reached the point where all the data was actually there, the browser would not download it as a file. The "window.open" was the missing part on the client's side!

Comment: Thanks for the tip: I did find that on both Mac/PC it seemed to work fine. Just using a normal pug file with an "a".  2020.

Answer (score 1):

**You can easliy achieve with a npm package**

*On express server:*

```
    const csvwriter = require('csv-writer');
    let createCsvWriter = csvwriter.createObjectCsvWriter;
    router.get('/downloadcsvfromJSON', (req, res) => {
         const dataArray= [{"id":"1","name":"BOB"},{"id":"2","name":"JACK"}];
         const path = 'sample.csv';
         const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
           path: path,
           header: [{ id:'id',title:'ID'},{id:'name',title:'Name' }]});
         });
         try 
         {
              csvWriter.writeRecords(userLogsArray)
              .then(() => {res.download(path);});
         }
         catch (error) 
         {
           console.log(error);
         }
```

*On browser:*

```
http://localhost:3000/downloadcsvfromJSON/
```

You will be able to download the csv file.