# File upload and download - Angular with Node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ng-file-upload

I am working on project where I have to store a file/img/pdf for a particular user instance and retrieve the files when the user logged in.

So the theme is, whenever user uploads a file it should be populated in his screen like profile pictures, invoice PDF's etc.,

Moreover, I just want to perform a carousel slideshow of uploaded images by user.

I came through several baked in modules such as ng-file-upload in angular and I was successful in uploading files too but how can I retrieve the particular file from the server and display them to user?

What is the best practice to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a very broad question.

Comment: You can read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express  on how to download a file from Node. Then on the front-end you can just have and `<img ...>` with src pointing to that url.

Comment: Thank you so much. it really helps.