# Download a .docx file from NodeJS Server using Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to prompt the user for file download using express's res.download but it does not seem to work and gives an error in the console.

Here is my code

```
router.get('/download', function(req, res){

    var file = __dirname + '/public/template.docx';
    res.download(file);

});
```

Which gives me the following error

> ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0

Comment: Do you have tried `res.set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');` and `res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=template.docx')`?

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express).

Comment: @HasanBayat still gives the same error

Comment: Do you have tried the solution at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express)?

Comment: This solution includes using res.download which is not working for me

Comment: Do you have tried the Content-Type header? Also try `res.end();`.

Comment: Do you mean:

    `res.set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'); 
    res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=template.docx');
    var file = __dirname + '/public/template.docx';
    res.sendFile(file);
    res.end();`

still does not work and gives this error 
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: How about Streaming? Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express) old solution not the new update then report back.

Comment: I have tried `res.download();` with a demo.docx file and it works. create a new fresh folder with fresh expressjs installed and do the same job with only one router.

Comment: @HasanBayat can you show me your work

Comment: A simple Hello World with your .docx file download `const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.get('/download', function(req, res) {
  res.download('./demo.docx')
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})`.

Comment: You can download .docx file from [here](https://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're possibly doing something else wrong. Here's a functional example:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/download-docx', (req, res) => {
  const docPath = path.join(__dirname, 'demo.docx');
  res.download(docPath, 'demo.docx', function(err){
    if (err) {
      // if the file download fails, we throw an error
      throw err;
    }
  });
})

const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});
```

It assumes there's a `demo.docx` file in the same directory the above file is in. If you'd like a completely functional example you can edit I built one for you on [glitch.com](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/file-download-example). One small catch, glitch doesn't show the `demo.docx` file in the file tree, but rest assured it is actually there. You can confirm for yourself using the console option in the Advanced Options menu in the top left.