# Doc File not downloading in Express and React

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, express

I am downloading files in express js and react Js  with ajax request. pdf , php , zip , etc every file is downloading but when i want to download docx file it is not working.

my code dowload every type of file but not docx file.

Front End Code

```
  getfile(cell) {



    console.log(cell)

    var filename = cell ;

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/filedownload/' + filename,
      success: function () {
        window.open('/filedownload/' + filename, '_blank');
      }
    });

  }
```

server side code

```
app.get('/filedownload/:filename', function (req, res) {

    var file = req.params.filename

    res.download(__dirname + '/uploads/' + file);

  });
```

Comment: are u sure the path is correctly set for .docx file?

Comment: yeah , i am sure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a file from NodeJS Server using Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way. If you do an AJAX request the most likely thing you'll get is a file blob on success.

You can try using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/downloadjs) to download files on the client after an ajax request.

This lib actually let's you download straight from an url like:

```
download("/robots.txt");
```

Using a [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for AJAX request, I've done this:

```
// Using async/await ES6 javascript

const res = await fetch(fileDownloadUrl);

const fileBlob = await res.blob();

// using downloadjs https://www.npmjs.com/package/downloadjs
download(fileBlob);
```

In your case you must make sure you receive the blob