# React JS + API Node JS, download file blob

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm working on a project with React JS as frontend framework and a node JS API.

My Database is a MySQL and i store files (png, csv, docx ...) as BLOB in it.

When i call my API with React i'm getting the file with the type : buffer.

How i can download it ?

Comment: How do you download it in the frontend or how you send it from the backend? Your question already has an answer on SO. I have had the same question before. Look at articles like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express