# how to download file with SFTP in Node from browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, download, sftp

I am trying to download some files using SFTP in Node. I know I have to handle the stream but I am not sure how I should do this and save the file in my local machine (in the downloads folder).

```
app.get('/download', (req, res) => {
    var Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
    var sftp = new Client();

    var config = {
        host: 'host123',
        port: '22',
        username: 'username',
        password: 'secretpassword'
    };

    sftp.connect(config).then((data) => {
        res.download(data);
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

reference [Download a file from NodeJS Server using Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express)

sftp.connect allow you stream data. you can pipe it to response

```
app.get('/download', (req, res) => {
                var Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
                var sftp = new Client();

    var config = {
            host: 'host123',
            port: '22',
            username: 'username',
            password: 'secretpassword'
    };

    sftp.connect(config)
    .then(()=>{
        return sftp.get(remoteFilePath, [useCompression], [encoding]);
    })
    .then((data) => {
            fs.createWriteStream(data).pipe(res);
    });
});
```

Comment: I get a "(node:14796) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer".

Comment: I changed the `remoteFilePath` to the location of the file I am trying to get, but when I did, I got an error code `(node:7952) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: useCompression is not defined`.