# Node.js binary to PDF

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pdf

I have got a express server, which creates a pdf file.

I am trying to send this file to the client:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

function download(req, res) {
  var filePath = '/../../myPdf.pdf';

  fs.readFile(__dirname + filePath, function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw new Error(err);
    console.log('yeyy, no errors :)');

    if (!data) throw new Error('Expected data, but got', data);
    console.log('got data', data);

    res.contentType('application/pdf');
    res.send(data);
  });
}
```

On the client I want to download it:

```js
  _handleDownloadAll = async () => {
    console.log('handle download all');
    const response = await request.get(
      `http://localhost:3000/download?accessToken=${localStorage.getItem(
        'accessToken'
      )}`
    );

    console.log(response);
  };
```

I recieve an body.text like

```js
%PDF-1.4↵1 0 obj↵<<↵/Title (��)↵/Creator (��)↵/Producer (��Qt 5.5.1)↵
```

but I can't achieve a download.

How can I create a PDF from the data OR directly download it from the server?

**I've got it working:**
The answer was pretty simple. I just let the browser handle the download with an html anchor tag:
server:

```js
function download(req, res) {
  const { creditor } = req.query;
  const filePath =  `/../../${creditor}.pdf`;

  res.download(__dirname + filePath);
}
```

client:

```js
<a href{`${BASE_URL}?accessToken=${accessToken}&creditor=${creditorId}`} download>Download</a>
```

Comment: `readFile` returns a [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_buffer) which is raw bytes. You're sending these raw bytes back to the client which is logging them to the console. The `body.text` you see is to be expected. You will need to write these bytes to a file using `fs.writeFile` or similar.

Comment: please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express

Answer (score 1):

The result is the string of the binary. We use base 64 to convert from binary to pdf

> `var buffer = Buffer.from(result['textBinary'], 'base64')`
> `fs.writeFileSync('/path/to/my/file.pdf', buffer)`

Answer (score 0):

You can prompt the browser to download the file by setting the correct content-disposition header:

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=myfile.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

`readFile` returns a [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_buffer) which is a wrapper around bytes. You're sending `Buffer` back to the client which is logging them to the console.

The body.text you see is to be expected.

You will need to write these bytes to a file using `fs.writeFile` or similar. Here's an example:

```
_handleDownloadAll = async () => {
  console.log('handle download all');
  const response = await request.get(
    `http://localhost:3000/download?accessToken=${localStorage.getItem(
      'accessToken'
    )}`
  );

  // load your response data into a Buffer
  let buffer = Buffer.from(response.body.text)

  // open the file in writing mode
  fs.open('/path/to/my/file.pdf', 'w', function(err, fd) {  
    if (err) {
        throw 'could not open file: ' + err;
    }

    // write the contents of the buffer
    fs.write(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        throw 'error writing file: ' + err;
      }
      fs.close(fd, function() {
          console.log('file written successfully');
      });
    });
  });
};
```

You may need to experiment with the buffer encoding, it defaults to `utf8`.

**Read this!**

The other option you may want to consider is generating the PDF on the server and simply sending the client a link to where it can download this.