# Download filename from NodeJS Server using Express

Tags: node.js, rest, express, download, filenames

I know there is already an answered question:
[Download a file from NodeJS Server using Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express)

**But I have still problems with the filename displayed in the browser download dialog.**

What I code:

```
private static async GetReport(req : Request, res : Response, route : myRoute)
{
        let data = route.mReportMap[req.query.guid];
        res.attachment(path.join(data.ReportPath, data.ReportFileName));
        console.log('*** HEADER CONTENT ***');
        console.log('x-powered-by: ' + res.getHeader('x-powered-by'));
        console.log('access-control-allow-origin: ' + res.getHeader('access-control-allow-origin'));
        console.log('content-type: ' + res.getHeader('content-type'));
        console.log('content-disposition: ' + res.getHeader('content-disposition'));

        res.download(path.join(data.ReportPath, data.ReportFileName), data.ReportFileName);
}
```

What the console says:

```
    *** HEADER CONTENT ***
    x-powered-by: Express
    access-control-allow-origin: *
    content-type: application/zip
    content-disposition: attachment; 
    filename="20180724_Report.zip"
    2018-07-24 12:05:23|debug| POST /api/test/report/download?guid=b27fee1f-7da5-437c-9103-5da58ab01df8 HTTP/1.1 from http://localhost:4200/ with response  200 557458
```

What the browser download dialog displays:

[image: Chrome Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)]

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**The question is obsolete.**

Someone in my team coded a static filename in the frontend (for test purposes)...
Now I whet my double-handed axe, just for test purposes... ;-D

Thanks for your time anyway.