# Download PDF from http response with Axios

Tags: javascript, http, vue.js, axios

I am working on a Vue application with a Laravel back-end API. After clicking on a link I would like to do a call to the server to download a certain file (most of the time a PDF file). When I do a `get` request with `axios` I get a PDF in return, in the body of the response. I would like to download that file directly.

To give you a better view of how the response is looking like:

[image]
(note: I know a real text response is better than an image but I don't see any way to return that because of the length of the actual PDF content..)

Is there any way of downloading that file with JavaScript or something? It has to be specific a direct download without clicking on the button again.

Code

```
// This method gets called when clicking on a link
downloadFile(id) {
    const specificationId = this.$route.params.specificationId;

    axios
        .get(`${this.$API_URL}/api/v1/suppliersmanagement/product-specifications/${specificationId}/fileupload/${id}/download`, {
            headers: this.headers,
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            // Direct download the file here..
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
},
```

Comment: Take a look at [this link](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/May/21/Downloading-a-File-with-a-Save-As-Dialog-in-ASPNET). While it is in asp.net, your server code should set the headers right, for the client to cause a prompt or show pdf.

Answer (score 47):

As @Sandip Nirmal suggested I've used `downloadjs` and that worked out pretty good! Had to make a few adjustments to my code but in the end it worked out.

My new code

```
// npm i downloadjs
import download from 'downloadjs'

// method
downloadFile(file) {
    const specificationId = this.$route.params.specificationId;

    axios
        .get(`${this.$API_URL}/api/v1/suppliersmanagement/product-specifications/${specificationId}/fileupload/${file.id}/download`, {
            headers: this.headers,
            responseType: 'blob', // had to add this one here
        })
        .then(response => {
           const content = response.headers['content-type'];
           download(response.data, file.file_name, content)
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
},
```

Comment: I was also able to make it work for PDFs using downloadjs. Thanks for the tip. People should note that `refereceType: 'blob'` is required.

Comment: Great answer, worked straight forward..thanks!

Comment: Using arraybuffer fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This is a workaround but does not answer the question of how does one 'Download PDF from http response with Axios'.

Answer (score 28):

You should use 'responseType' option. For example:

```
axios.get(
  url, 
  {responseType: 'blob'} // !!!
).then((response) => {
  window.open(URL.createObjectURL(response.data));
})
```

Comment: That was it! To correctly receive a pdf from the server, I had to use `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` in the config field of the httpService call. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

You have 2 options for this. If you want to do it from server and if you are using Node.js as a backend. You can do it easily using `res.download` method of express. You can follow this answer for that [Download a file from NodeJS Server using Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express).

But if you want to handle it from client then there are few options since you can't use axios, XHR, fetch to download file directly. You can either use `download.js` or write your own code in following way.

```
return axios({
    url: '/download', // download url
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      mode: 'no-cors'
    }
  })
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      var a = document.createElement('a')
      a.href = url
      a.download = fileName
      a.click()
      a.remove()
      setTimeout(() => window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url), 100)
    })
```

Since response returned from server is in `json` format you need to convert it into `ObjectURL` and set it to anchor tag.

If you sneak inside `download.js` code you will find same implementation.

Comment: As you can read in my post, I don't use Node.js but I use Laravel. Anyway, I will look into download.js

Comment: ``download.js`` does the same exact thing like above mentioned code snippet.

Comment: `response.blob is not a function` .     
      
// - Browser only: FormData, File, Blob .     
// - Node only: Stream, Buffer .     
      
I'm working on a Node JS CLI tool. I'm trying to replicate the `.blob()` approach with `stream`.

Comment: I was able to use `data.pipe(writer)` and a `writer.on("finish")` listener to save and then serve the file locally in my CLI tool.

Answer (score 6):

### 2022 answer: using node.js, fs.promises and async/await

The key is using [`responseType: 'stream'` per the Axios docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro).

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { writeFile } from 'fs/promises';

const downloadFile = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get('https://someurl', {
    params: {
      // ...
    },
    // See https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro
    responseType: 'stream',
  });
  const pdfContents = response.data;
  await writeFile('file.pdf', pdfContents);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const downloadPDF = (id, fileName) => {
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: `https://api.example.com/pdf/invoice/${id}`,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        responseType: 'blob'
    }).then(function (response) {
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
        a.download = `${fileName}.pdf`;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        a.remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
download(filename) {
  fetch(url , { headers })
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
  .then(uril => {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = uril;
    link.download = filename + ".csv";
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  });
}
```

here I want to download a CSV file, So I add .csv to the filename.

Comment: Might as well open a popup instead of injecting an element and then firing a `click` event

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue, and this is how I solved it.

Below is how i download the pdf through NodeJs and Axios:

```
 const url = `https://www.buds.com.ua/images/Lorem_ipsum.pdf`;
 return await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'stream' });
```

If you want to forward the .pdf content through your own api you will have to send it as *stream of data*
Below is implementation for it:

```
response.data.pipe(res);
```

Hence complete code for your API would be:

```
async function forwardPDF(req, res) {
  try {
    // Fetch the PDF from the URL
    const url = `https://www.buds.com.ua/images/Lorem_ipsum.pdf`;
    const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'stream' });

    // Pipe the PDF to the response
    response.data.pipe(res);

  } catch (error) {
    const header = Header(true, error.statusCode, error.message, error.stack);
    res.send(Response(header, {}));
  }
}
```