# Node - Download in browser an existing excel

Tags: node.js, excel, download, export-to-excel

I created an excel file using using excel4node library, it is saved in the server side. Does anybody know how can I simulate a client download in the browser for it? I saw that there are some libraries 'download', 'file-saver', none of them work server side.
Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express), assuming your using expressjs.

Comment: Can you post your server code

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by using

```
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
  res.sendFile(path);
```