# Sending client file download link

Tags: node.js, express, static-files

I have a `nodejs` backend and I want to send a file download link to the client such that, the file is directly accessible by the client. The file types are `JPEG` and `PNG`. Currently, I am serving these files as `data-uri` but, due to a change in requirements, I must send a download link in response to the file request and, client can download the file later using that link.

Now the current workflow exposes a path `/getAvatar`. This path should send a response back to the client with the file link. The file, is stored in `/assets/avatars` relative to the server root. I know I can `express.static` middleware to send back static resources. However, the methods I have seen so far, `res.send()` and `res.download()` both tries to send the file as attachment rather a link that can be used later to download.

Basically, the behavior is like a regular file sharing site where, once a file is clicked, a link to it is generated which, is used for downloading the file. How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express

Comment: in same method pass parameter like {type: 'avatar or URL'} and based on type return the data