# How to generate a word document with a click of a button by using the officeGen module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have been trying for a couple of days to write a web app to generate a word document with a click of a button.
This is what I did so far:

> Project structure:

[image]

> server.js

```
console.log('Server-side code running');

const express = require('express');

const app = express();

// serve files from the public directory
app.use(express.static('public'));

// serve the homepage
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

> client.js

```
var createDocumentService = require('../services/generateDocumentService.js');
console.log('Client-side code running');

const button = document.getElementById('myButton');
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('button was clicked');
createDocumentService.generateDocument();
```

});

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Report Generation</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Generate Word Document With a click of a button!</h1>
    <button id="myButton">Click me!</button>
  </body>
  <script src="client.js"></script>
</html>
```

> generateDocumentService.js

```
var async = require('async')
const officegen = require('officegen')

var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')
var generateDocument = function () { //will search for an exact match

  console.log('%c%s', 'color: #f2ceb6', 'INSIDE SERVICE GENERATION DOCUMENT');
  //var outDir = path.join(__dirname, '../tmp/')

  // var themeXml = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'themes/testTheme.xml'), 'utf8')

  var docx = officegen({
    type: 'docx',
    orientation: 'portrait',
    pageMargins: {
      top: 1000,
      left: 1000,
      bottom: 1000,
      right: 1000
    }
    // The theme support is NOT working yet...
    // themeXml: themeXml
  })

  // Remove this comment in case of debugging Officegen:
  // officegen.setVerboseMode ( true )

  docx.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err)
  })


  pObj = docx.createP({
    align: 'center'
  })

  pObj.addText(' Risk Analysis Report', {
    font_face: 'Arial',
    font_size: 40
  })
  //pObj.addLineBreak()
  pObj = docx.createP({
    backline: 'E0E0E0'
  })

  pObj.addText('Author: Sami Habboubi', {
    bold: true
  })
  pObj = docx.createP({
    backline: 'E0E0E0'
  })

  pObj.addText('Date: 11/06/2019')

  pObj = docx.createP({
    align: 'center'
  })

  pObj.addText('Business Process General Information', {
    border: 'dotted',
    borderSize: 12,
    borderColor: '88CCFF',
    bold: true
  })
  var table = [
    [{
        opts: {
          cellColWidth: 4261,
          b: true,
          sz: '10',
          shd: {
            fill: '7F7F7F',
            themeFill: 'Arial',
            themeFillTint: '20'
          },
          fontFamily: 'Arial'
        }
      },
      {
        opts: {
          b: true,
          align: 'left',
          shd: {
            fill: '92CDDC',
            themeFill: 'text1',
            themeFillTint: '80'
          },
          fontFamily: 'Avenir Book'
        }
      }
    ],
    ['1. What are your main business objectives? ', 'All grown-ups were once children'],
    ['2. In which sites(Countries) your team is located?', 'there is no harm in putting off a piece of work until another day.'],
    [
      '3. What are your key business processes? How are they ranked in terms of criticality?',
      '4. But when it is a matter of baobabs, that always means a catastrophe.'
    ],
    ['5. What are your main interactions with other Business Lines?', 'watch out for the baobabs!']
  ]

  var tableStyle = {
    tableColWidth: 4261,
    tableSize: 24,
    tableColor: 'ada',
    tableAlign: 'left',
    tableFontFamily: 'Arial',
  }

  pObj = docx.createTable(table, tableStyle, )
  docx.putPageBreak()

  var pObj = docx.createP()

  pObj.addText('Simple')
  pObj.addText(' with color', {
    color: '000088'
  })
  pObj.addText(' and back color.', {
    color: '00ffff',
    back: '000088'
  })

  pObj = docx.createP()

  pObj.addText('Since ')
  pObj.addText('officegen 0.2.12', {
    back: '00ffff',
    shdType: 'pct12',
    shdColor: 'ff0000'
  }) // Use pattern in the background.
  pObj.addText(' you can do ')
  pObj.addText('more cool ', {
    highlight: true
  }) // Highlight!
  pObj.addText('stuff!', {
    highlight: 'darkGreen'
  }) // Different highlight color.

  pObj = docx.createP()

  pObj.addText('Even add ')
  pObj.addText('external link', {
    link: 'https://github.com'
  })
  pObj.addText('!')

  pObj = docx.createP()

  pObj.addText('Bold + underline', {
    bold: true,
    underline: true
  })

  pObj = docx.createP({
    align: 'center'
  })

  pObj.addText('Center this text', {
    border: 'dotted',
    borderSize: 12,
    borderColor: '88CCFF'
  })

  pObj = docx.createP()
  pObj.options.align = 'right'

  pObj.addText('Align this text to the right.')

  pObj = docx.createP()

  pObj.addText('Those two lines are in the same paragraph,')
  pObj.addLineBreak()
  pObj.addText('but they are separated by a line break.')

  docx.putPageBreak()

  pObj = docx.createP()

  pObj.addText('Fonts face only.', {
    font_face: 'Arial'
  })
  pObj.addText(' Fonts face and size.', {
    font_face: 'Arial',
    font_size: 40
  })

  docx.putPageBreak()

  pObj = docx.createP()

  //pObj.addImage(path.resolve(__dirname, 'images_for_examples/image3.png'))

  docx.putPageBreak()

  pObj = docx.createP()

  //pObj.addImage(path.resolve(__dirname, 'images_for_examples/image1.png'))

  pObj = docx.createP()

  //pObj.addImage(path.resolve(__dirname, 'images_for_examples/sword_001.png'))
  //pObj.addImage(path.resolve(__dirname, 'images_for_examples/sword_002.png'))
  //pObj.addImage(path.resolve(__dirname, 'images_for_examples/sword_003.png'))
  //pObj.addText('... some text here ...', { font_face: 'Arial' })
  //pObj.addImage(path.resolve(__dirname, 'images_for_examples/sword_004.png'))

  pObj = docx.createP()

  //pObj.addImage(path.resolve(__dirname, 'images_for_examples/image1.png'))

  docx.putPageBreak()

  pObj = docx.createListOfNumbers()

  pObj.addText('Option 1')

  pObj = docx.createListOfNumbers()

  pObj.addText('Option 2')

  pObj.addHorizontalLine()

  pObj = docx.createP({
    backline: 'E0E0E0'
  })

  pObj.addText('Backline text1')

  pObj.addText(' text2')

  pObj = docx.createP()

  pObj.addText('Strikethrough text', {
    strikethrough: true
  })

  pObj.addText('superscript', {
    superscript: true
  })
  pObj.addText('subscript', {
    subscript: true
  })

  var table = [
    [{
        val: 'No.',
        opts: {
          cellColWidth: 4261,
          b: true,
          sz: '48',
          shd: {
            fill: '7F7F7F',
            themeFill: 'text1',
            themeFillTint: '80'
          },
          fontFamily: 'Avenir Book'
        }
      },
      {
        val: 'Title1',
        opts: {
          b: true,
          color: 'A00000',
          align: 'left',
          shd: {
            fill: '92CDDC',
            themeFill: 'text1',
            themeFillTint: '80'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        val: 'Title2',
        opts: {
          align: 'left',
          cellColWidth: 42,
          b: true,
          sz: '48',
          shd: {
            fill: '92CDDC',
            themeFill: 'text1',
            themeFillTint: '80'
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    [1, 'All grown-ups were once children', ''],
    [2, 'there is no harm in putting off a piece of work until another day.', ''],
    [
      3,
      'But when it is a matter of baobabs, that always means a catastrophe.',
      ''
    ],
    [4, 'watch out for the baobabs!', 'END']
  ]

  var tableStyle = {
    tableColWidth: 4261,
    tableSize: 24,
    tableColor: 'ada',
    tableAlign: 'left',
    tableFontFamily: 'Comic Sans MS'
  }

  pObj = docx.createTable(table, tableStyle)

  var out = fs.createWriteStream(path.join('Risk Analysis Report.docx'))

  out.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err)
  })

  async.parallel(
    [
      function (done) {
        out.on('close', function () {
          console.log('Finish to create a DOCX file.')
          done(null)
        })
        docx.generate(out)
      }
    ],
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('error: ' + err)
      } // Endif.
    }
  )
}
module.exports.generateDocument = generateDocument;
```

What I want is:
Use the **generateDocument** method defined in **generateDocumentService** inside the button code defined in **client.js**:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('button was clicked');
createDocumentService.generateDocument();
});
```

In order to do so, I have to use this inside **client.js**:

```
var createDocumentService = require('../services/generateDocumentService.js');
```

My problem is that I cannot use require in client.js because it's a node.js library so it cannot be ran on the client side.
After I have made some research, I found-out that I can use webpack, browserfy or require.js to solve this issue.
But, since **generateDocument** method uses the **fs** module. I don't think it would be wise to expose the writing and reading files on the client side.
Finally, here are my questions:
1/ What is the right way of calling the **generateDocument** method inside the button event listener?  Should I use webpack,browserfy or require.js? If not what is the alternative?
2/ Was I right when I said:
*I don't think it would be wise to expose the writing and reading files on the client side.*
I hope I was clear enough.
I really need to reach this goal of generating word document with a click of a button using officeGen in a couple of days.  So any help is warmly welcome :))

Comment: Why can't you put the code in server side and expose a route calling the function? And after generating the Give him a download link via the `express.static` binding? or can make a download route for that.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty that's a good idea actually I will try it out.:))  But, what I truly want is that when the user clicks on the button the generation of the documents happens and then it downloads.

Comment: Now, when you create a route the `res` is actually a writableStream. So you just need to add `res.setHeader` to set the header and `docx.generate(res)` (instead of out). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express

Comment: @AritraChakraborty alright! Thank you. I will try that out and if it worked I will post an answer :)

Comment: @AritraChakraborty I did what you said. But, somehow the file doesn't get downloaded. Please check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56611124/button-to-download-a-document-implemented-with-express-js-and-node-js-isnt-work