# How to convert blob to xlsx or csv?

Tags: javascript, csv, dataset, blob, xlsx

The frontend of the application having a file download option (which can be in the following format: xlsx, csv, dat).
For that, I use [fileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

Everything works fine for the format `.dat/.csv` but for the `.xlsx` it does not work the files are corrupted.

I tested the conversion with the following formats :

- `utf8`
- `base64`
- `binary`

Here's how I do :

```js
// /* BACK */ //
// data is 
fs.readFile(filePath, (err, data) {...})

// the api give this answer the important part is "filename" & "data"
{"status":"ok","context":"writing the intermediate file","target":"/temp/","fileName":"name.xlsx","data":{"type":"Buffer","data":[72,82,65,67,67,69,83,83,32,10]}}
```

```js
// /* FRONT */ //
let json = JSON.stringify(data)
let buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.parse(json).data)
let read = buffer.toString('utf8')
let blob = new Blob([read])
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for anybody who pass in this topic, my solution :

*(keep in mind the real better solution for dl a file : send file in api response with header 'Content-disposition' or use express for that [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express))*

#### The back (Node) work like this :

```js
 fs.readFile(filePath, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`-------- oups error - read --------`)
      console.log(err)
      res.send({ status: `erreur`, context: `read the source file`, id: err.errno, code: err.code, message: err.message.replace(/\\/g, '/') })
    } else {
      res.send({ status: `ok`, context: `send data file`, target: target, fileName: fileName, data: data })
    } 
  })
```

Here :

- target is the path for the front with the name of the file and his
  extension (`/path/name.ext`)
- fileName is juste the name and the extension (`name.ext`)
- data is the data send by the readFile (`{"type":"Buffer","data":[72,82,65,67,67,69,83,83,32,10]}`)

#### The front (React) work like this :

```js
fetch(targetUrl)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status !== `ok`) {
        this.setState({
          errorDlFile: true,
          errorDlFile_context: res.context,
          errorDlFile_id: res.id,
          errorDlFile_code: res.code,
          errorDlFile_message: res.message
        })
      } else {  
        const target = res.target
        const fileName = res.fileName
        const data = res.data
        const splitName = res.fileName.split('.')
        const format = splitName[splitName.length-1]

        // file saver blob solution
        let json = JSON.stringify(data)
        let buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.parse(json).data)
        let readUTF8 = buffer.toString('utf8')
        let blob = ''

        if (format === 'xlsx') {
          blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' })
        } else if (format === 'csv') {
          blob = new Blob([readUTF8], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' })
        } else {
          blob = new Blob([readUTF8])
        }

        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName)

      }
    })
```

Comment: charset content-type for "csv" is `text/csv`

Answer (score 0):

@Hadock
if you want to download file with .csv extension then you need to pass the type of file like

```
let blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });
```

instead of

```
let blob = new Blob([read])
```

and don't forgot to send filename with extension (test.csv).

For excel file I used different plugin *exceljs* [demo](https://github.com/grishabh1992/angular-excel-export).

Comment: It's good for .csv, but not for .xlsx. I add some details in my post like the JSON that is sent by my backend. I read your example, but I do not understand how I should store the data in the file.

Comment: @Hadock Create a plunker, I will help you to generate excel file.

Answer (score 0):

you can't save json data directly to .xlsx file, you can convert json data to excel format using library like 'sheetjs' (https://sheetjs.com/)

```
var ws_name = filename;//"SheetJS";
var wb = new Workbook(), ws = sheet_from_array_of_arrays(data);
/* add worksheet to workbook */
wb.SheetNames.push(ws_name);
wb.Sheets[ws_name] = ws;
var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', bookSST: true, type: 'binary' });
saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)], { type: "application/octet-stream" }), filename + ".xlsx")
```

Comment: why is ``sheet_from_array_of_arrays`` and ``s2ab`` I can't import them and I don't see them in the sheetjs doc

Comment: Ok the correct path is ``XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(data)`` and ``XLSX.utils.s2ab(wbout)``.
Anyway my data is not a ``aoa`` is a buffer ``[72,82,65,67,67,69,83,83,32,10]``