# I want to download a zip file in MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

Here is frontend code (Angular):-

```
  download(user) {


    this.clientAPI.get(Endpoints.DOWNLOAD).toPromise()
      .then(res => {
      
        let blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(res.file)], { type: 'application/zip' });
          console.log('blob',blob);
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = (URL.createObjectURL(blob));
        a.download = res.filename;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
         a.remove();
        //  this.downloadComplete(user);
      })
      .catch(err => console.error("download error = ", err))
  }

Here is my backend code (Node Js):-

exports.download = function (req, res) {

  let file = process.env.NOCE_ENV === 'local' ? `${process.cwd()}/server/downloads/eFAST-Release-20.5.17.19.zip` :
    `${process.cwd()}/server/downloads/eFAST-Release-20.5.17.19.zip`;
  let filename = path.basename(file);
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
  res.setHeader('Content-type', "application/zip");
  let filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  
 // console.log('filestream',filenter code hereestream)
  res.jsonp({ filename: filename, file: filestream });
};
```

I am able to download the file but that is not in zip format . that is in .txt format and zero byte.

Please have a look and let me know hpw can i do this ?

Comment: Are you trying to unzip a downloaded zip file on the client? There are libraries on npm for that `zip.js` and more.

Comment: i am just trying to download the zip file

Answer (score 0):

You can use res.download("link_to_file") in express to download it.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express).

> i used res.download but how could i manage this in angular ?

I'm not sure about angular but I think you can use plain js here to navigate to new tab where download will start.

```js
window.open('https://YOUR-LINK-TO-FILE/download','_blank')
```

By the way, you have typo: process.env.NOCE_ENV

Comment: i used res.download but how could i manage this in angular ?

Comment: but i don't want to use window.open

Comment: @Deepikavijay Ok, I didn't used angular for that but for React I used npm package that initiates Save File dialog on the page. So you can try to find something like that https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-saver

or look into their source code to implement it for youself

Comment: @Deepikavijay I think instead of window.open you can just place the link to the file like that `<a ng-href="{{linkToFile}}" target="_self"></a>` and then use express with res.download

Comment: I am trying by this

 download(user) {

    this.clientAPI.get(Endpoints.DOWNLOAD).toPromise()
    .then(res => {
      let a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = (URL.createObjectURL(res));
      a.download = 'test';
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      a.remove();
    });

and in backend

exports.download = function (req, res) {

  let file = process.env.NOCE_ENV === 'local' ? `${process.cwd()}/server/downloads/eFAST-Release-20.5.17.19.zip` :
    `${process.cwd()}/server/downloads/eFAST-Release-20.5.17.19.zip`;
  
 res.download(file);
};

Comment: but all is vain

Answer (score 0):

You need to pipe the filestream (from `fs.createReadStream()`) into `res` (the response). If you read the nodejs docs about `stream` and `http`, one will notice that `res` is actually also a `Writable` stream that you can *pipe* into like:

```js
// set status code
res.setStatus(200); // 200 means ok
// set headers beforehand
// octet-stream means binary
res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/octet-stream');
filestream.pipe(res);
```

Streams are what make NodeJS powerful and efficient. It's an event-based emitter that passes chunks of data at a threshold limit by a configurable `highWaterMark` property (I think 16KB per chunk). You normally *pipe* a `Readable` into a `Writable` stream (in your case a readable file stream into a writable http response stream). You can read more about them here: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html