# How to start properly http server and host many of sources files in different folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, httpserver

So, the question is:
I have some files that I need to host for my running app, in order to get all that stuff in response from the HTTP server. If I started the HTTP server in the source folder - then all works fine and I can get all my files. But I need to start the HTTP server above my source folder because I have many of them. Suppose that I have 100 different source folders. is it mean that I need to start 100 servers? To avoid it I wanna run single global HTTP server. Also, I have in my source folders mapping that gives the path (hardcoded) to resources and this path starts from source folder like: source/some_file.png
If I run the server in this directory then I will be able to access the file on url
http://localhost:8083/some_file.png.
But if I start the server in the folder above like: main_dir/source then I cannot access the file http://localhost:8083/some_file.png. And my response fails with error code 404.
I've tried to intercept the request and inject the path folder so I get the url file address http://localhost:8083/source/some_file.png. It's working, but then I have different error..
May be there is some other way to start a global http server and access the file one folder below in path?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a doc about serving file with NodeJS built in server: [doc](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/).
So, 2 possibilities:

- Serve files yourself with a list

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');

const folderArray = ["main_dir", "another_dir", ...];

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  folderArray.forEach((folder) => {
  try {
    fs.accessSync(`${folder}/${}req.url` /* Change req.url for your url or parameter */, fs.constants.F_OK);
    console.log('File exists');
    const data = fs.readFileSync(`${folder}/${}req.url`); // Handle this error correctly
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
    // You would want to break the loop here as it's already served. 
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('No file!');
  }
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

- Or let a module do it for you: [node-static](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static) (of course, adapte server folder with your folder array :D).

If you want to download the file, check out this answer: [download file with express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express).

Cheers  !