# Nodsjs serve static files but change filename when downloading

Tags: node.js, express

I want to serve many files in a folder and thats possible with `app.use('/files', express.static('uploads'));`.

All my files have an uuid as suffix for example: `73694640-44e9-448d-bf2f-29148b59180b_myfile.txt`.

Is there a short way to serve all files in this folder but when downloading them, the filename should be without the suffix/uuid?

Like `http://localhost/files/73694640-44e9-448d-bf2f-29148b59180b_myfile.txt` will download `myfile.txt`.

Comment: there should be some logic in your code, right which is adding the UUID?

Comment: @RaviKumarGupta The uuid get`s added to the file name to prevent duplication when the files get's uploaded. I think I need to edit my question a bit..

Comment: I got your point. That's what I am asking - is UUID being added to your written code or some library? If its done by your code, you can edit the file name to remove the suffix also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that can make this happen:

```
app.get('/files/:file', (req, res) => {
    res.download(`./uploads/${req.params.file}`, req.params.file.substring(req.params.file.indexOf('_') + 1))
})
```

I removed the `app.use('/files', express.static('uploads'));` because the new route handles all the files in the `uploads` folder.

`app.get('/files/:file', (req, res) => {` takes the filename from the url as parameter. With this we can just send the file as download with `` res.download(`./uploads/${req.params.file} ``.

The filename can be edit to remove the suffix. First we look where the first `_` apears, take this index + 1 and create a substring of the string after the suffix: `req.params.file.substring(req.params.file.indexOf('_') + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here : [Download a file from NodeJS Server using Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server) . Both using express and without using express.

It is too simple if you are using Express. Here is the documentation for [res.download](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.download). I can't believe that the solution is just one line of code :

> res.download('/path/to/file.txt', 'newname.txt');

Comment: Thanks for the info how to do that :) I did write this code to replace the serve code: `app.get('/files/:file', (req, res) => {
  res.download(`./uploads/${req.params.file}`, req.params.file.substring(req.params.file.indexOf('_') + 1))
})`. PS: You can copy this code to your answer to make it complete.